# How to fix 'Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.4.0-5326820.' error in android studio 3.4

Tags: android-studio-3.4

I have downloaded the aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows file but I don't know what to do with it

I've tried downgrading gradle to 3.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Goto tools>Sdk manager > tools > reinstall and install tools repository 
after it restart android studio and stay connected to internet.